# CSS tips extJS 4

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4

I would like to implement tips in my web application, but i don't want them on the bottom like the sencha examples.  I prefer to have them on top and centered.

So I dropped the target conf in my tips and tried to add some of my own css. My custom css for the background works perfect, but the left/top css are overridden by ext.

How do I stop the Extjs css from overriding my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add !Important, after your css style.

for example:

```
    #example {    
                position: absolute !important;
             }
```

Comment: welcome @Belbarrin . kindly vote the answer as useful . thanks :)